# When reading data from a NetworkStream, is there a way to read all the data at once?

Tags: c#, arrays, sockets, dynamic, networkstream

I'm making a program that uses 'NetworkStream' from the Console to send data.

MSDN TcpListener Class Example uses 'while' when reading data from 'NetworkStream'.

Instead of using `while`, I want to read all the data received in `NetworkStream` all at once.

Is there a way to dynamically size the buffer and read the data without using `while`?

```cs
...

byte[] bytes = new byte[256];
string data = null;

...

int i;
while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
{
  data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
  Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}, data);
}
```

I tried to use `List<byte>`, but it failed because `stream.Read` could not be put into the buffer.

Comment: `var ms = new MemoryStream(); stream.CopyTo(ms); var bytes = ms.ToArray()`. But, bear in mind that data arrives over a network bit-by-bit, and it's fairly unlikely that you'll have received "everything" by the time that you decide to copy what you've received so far into an array

Comment: Just put this bit of code in a fuction returning  the array and reuse it in the way you want it to

Comment: @canton7 When I used the code you wrote, I confirmed that a byte value was entered into the `ms` MemoryStream. But when I do `int i = ms.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);`, the value of `i` is 0. Could you possibly know why?

Comment: @canton7 Oh, 
the same is true if you do `int i = ms.Read(bytes2, 0, bytes2.Length);` using `byte[] bytes2 = new byte[ms.Length];` instead of bytes.

Comment: Why are you doing `ms.Read`?

Comment: @canton7 Was it because there was data in `ms`?

However, if you do `stream.Read()`, it is the same.